# Laravel Fortify Logout Redirect

Tags: laravel

Hello guys is there any ways to redirect the logout function of Fortify?

```
<div class="nav-link" id="nav-bar-logoutbutton">                       
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
            @csrf
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="submit">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

this is my blade logout

Answer (score 18):

You can do the following:

Create a new `LogoutResponse` class and implement your redirect logic into the `toResponse` method:

**"app/Http/Responses/LogoutResponse.php"**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse as LogoutResponseContract;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LogoutResponse implements LogoutResponseContract
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse('', 204)
            : redirect('www.example.com');
    }
}
```

Now you can bind the new response into the service container in the `boot` method of your `FortifyServiceProvider`:

**"app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php"**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Responses\LogoutResponse::class
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Anyone know the reason why they done it this way? Why not use an optional config parameter in fortify config... A whole class just to redirect different seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: I agree with @TimvanUum with a clarification on why to do it in this way.

Comment: I also agree with the comments . There should have been a class for logout method to be in. And we could easily customize it. Thanks anyway! I can confirm that it works with Laravel 8.80.

Answer (score 11):

In your `config/fortify.php`, add:

```php
    'redirects' => [
        'logout' => 'login',
    ],
```

Comment: I am searching for so long without any result, and your answer saved my day.
This also works for anyone who use jetstream as its using fortify for the auth

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new post request in your `routes/web.php`

```
Route::post('logout', [ClientController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

Now in your controller, create a function to handle the request, make sure to include the Auth class at the top.

```
use Auth;

/* Process the logout request */
public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login')->with(['msg_body' => 'You signed out!']);
}
```

Instead of `/login`, you can redirect to anywhere.

Comment: It worked, but for that, I had to change the route name

Answer (score 0):

One can, alternatively, set redirect url after logout changing AuthenticatedSessionController#destroy.

**App/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController.php**

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
    ...

    return redirect('your_after_logout_page');
}
```