# Delete Cookies on Logout, Laravel 8.x, Fortify/Jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-fortify

Looking for a way to execute some code and, in particular delete / expire some cookies upon logging out from Laravel 8.x framework that is using Fortify and JetStream.

I noticed a couple of posts referencing the same issue, but not quite sure exactly which would be best and how to implement.

This one:  [Laravel Fortify Logout Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822861/laravel-fortify-logout-redirect) looks promising:

The 2nd option there says:

Create a new LogoutResponse class and implement your redirect logic into the toResponse method:

app/Http/Responses/LogoutResponse.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse as LogoutResponseContract;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LogoutResponse implements LogoutResponseContract
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse('', 204)
            : redirect('www.example.com');
    }
}
```

Now you can bind the new response into the service container in the boot method of your FortifyServiceProvider:

app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Responses\LogoutResponse::class
    );
}
```

See also:  [Laravel Fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify)

Seems like quite a bit to just do a redirect, but in my case I would actually want to expire a set of cookies and possibly do a little more housekeeping in app/Http/Responses/LogoutResponse.php.

Not exactly sure how to delete cookies in Laravel either, ?  In some instances the user might not actually even be logged in and I might want to delete a cookie when they close the browser (maybe by using JS to detect closing the browser and then deleting the Cookie (HTTP only cookie on the backend ?).

```
$cookie = \Cookie::forget('cookie_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my original post, this maybe seems to work, although the LogoutResponse is slightly different the what I posted originally because it is a modified version of what is on GitHub here:

[fortify/src/Http/Responses/LogoutResponse.php](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/1.x/src/Http/Responses/LogoutResponse.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse as LogoutResponseContract;

class LogoutResponse implements LogoutResponseContract
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */

    // Added this & also code in App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php to handle the deletion of the JWTVIEWER COOKIE.

    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        \Cookie::queue(\Cookie::forget('JWTVIEWER'));
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse('', 204)
                    : redirect('/');
    }
}
```

The namespace is different, and I added some code to delete the cookie that I wanted to expire upon logout.  The code is the FortifyServiceProvider.php is the same.

```
// Override the native LogoutResponse with one created in Responses.
$this->app->singleton(

    \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse::class,
    \App\Http\Responses\LogoutResponse::class
);
```

This seems to work if the user actually actively Logs Out.  I would be nice to also capture the user closing the browser or a tab without logging out, but that requires JS and is a bit problematic.

e.g. [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)